# Where is my abstract base MembershipProvider?

Tags: c#, security, namespaces, membership, membership-provider

I get that the `MembershipProvider` is in the `System.Web.Security` namespace.  I have added a reference `System.Web` in my project, I've added a `using System.Web.Security` directive in my .cs file - but as you can see, VS2010 does not believe me:

> The type or namespace name 'MembershipProvider' could not be found
>       (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: I'm probably missing something here...]

What am I missing here?

Comment: so, documentation bug: MemebershipProvider class -> assembly System.Web.dll, not really

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll`.

This is mentioned in the [MembershipProvider help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx):

```
Namespace:  System.Web.Security
Assembly:  System.Web.ApplicationServices (in System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have always just looked at the namespace, and never really paid attention to the assembly that it was in - learned something new today.

Comment: @ScottSEA: Yeah - the assembly is what needs to be referenced - the namespace is what goes in the "using XXX.XXX;"  Both need to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Google result of the day:

It is in the assembly [`System.Web.ApplicationServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx).

Comment: I Googled this to death but just wasn't putting in the right terms, apparently.

Comment: @ScottSEA just google the class name. The first hit is usually the msdn documentation page which contains information about the assembly that contains the class.